# How to write If - else if - else if - else in snowflake stored procedure

Tags: javascript, if-statement, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a situation where I have to write if- else if - else if - else in a snowflake stored procedure. I am aware that we can write if else , but not sure if we can write else if. Please let me know the syntax or the way to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snowflake stored procedures are (currently) Javascript. Here is a trivial example of a stored procedure with `IF... ELSE IF... ELSE` logic:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE if_else_if_test(MYSTR  VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$

  if (MYSTR == 'Y') {
    return 'Yes'
  }
  else if (MYSTR == 'N') {
    return 'No'
  }
  else {
    return 'Maybe'
  }

$$
;
CALL if_else_if_test('Y')
;
CALL if_else_if_test('N')
;
CALL if_else_if_test(NULL)
;
```